# Managed Account -- Required server permissions?

Tags: 2010

I set up a managed account for my Sharepoint 2010 Web Application.  I did this by first creating a local account on the system (in the "Users" group), then set up the web application, providing the managed account info when doing so.

Everything worked great for while until I tried to save a site template, and I noticed errors in the ULS log basically stating that the permission to the C:\windows\TEMP directory were insufficient.  So I added the "managed" local account to that folder giving full permissions and the site templates worked.

So I am curious, what is the *right* way to set up a managed account with respect to local server permissions?  Did I miss a step perhaps I should have added the user to a group other than Users?  Any help is appreciated even RTFM with a link would be great, I've been unable to find info on this aspect of managed accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in general it's not recommended that you run your SharePoint as Stand-Alone and this is the only mode that supports local users.

The recommended practise is to run as a Complete Farm and use domain account, when you use domain accounts as application pool accounts they will/should automatically be added to the group WSS_WPG and thereby be given access to c:\windows\temp

I'm not 100% sure the WSS_WPG group exists when running Stand-Alone but you should check that and if that's the case then give the account access through that.

Comment: Thank you Per -- the WSS_WPG group does exist in Standalone.  I appreciate the knowledge.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just wanted to update this.  When I checked the group membership for my managed account user, I found it was already a member of the WSS_WPG group.  So, giving the managed account a bit more permissions on the c:\windows\temp folder did the trick.  I suppose that an OOTB managed account with WSS_WPG membership isn't enough to create a site template, it should really be done by a member of the WSS_ADMIN_WPG group.  Most likely if I'd gone the powershell route as admin I'd not have had a problem.